# How to disable ListView items when I select an item in Multiple Select Mode in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-dialogfragment

I have a multiple selection `ListView` in dialog fragment and an `ArrayAdapter` like the following:

```
public class AnswerListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> list;

    public AnswerListAdapter (Context context, int resourceId, List<String> list) {
        super(context, resourceId, list);
        mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
        mContext = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.list = list;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView itemName;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder.itemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtAnswer);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.itemName.setText(list.get(position));
        return view;
    }

    public void toggleSelection(int position)
    {
        selectView(position, !mSelectedItemsIds.get(position));
    }

    public void selectView(int position, boolean value) {
        if (value)
            mSelectedItemsIds.put(position, value);
        else
            mSelectedItemsIds.delete(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public SparseBooleanArray getSelectedIds()
    {
        return mSelectedItemsIds;
    }
}
```

How I am going to use `.setEnable(false)` to the items which are not selected?

**For Example List items are: No,Yes,Yes-1,Yes-2 . If I choose No I want to disable the Yes items**